# Upper bound of number of k-tuples whose components are non-negative integers and sum up to n?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, linear-programming, integer-partitions

Is there any nontrivial upper bound for the size of $\{(x_1,\dots,x_k)\in\mathbb{N}^k:\sum_{i=1}^kx_i=n\}?$ We may assume $k,n$ are large enough but $k\ll n$, so an asymptotic bound is also helpful.

Comment: This can be computed exactly as ${{n+k-1}\choose {k-1}}$ or ${{n+k-1}\choose n}$, if that helps at all.

Comment: Oh, I see. By adding $k,$ it converges to the problem that $k$ positive integers summing up to $n.$

Comment: Exactly. ${}{}{}$